# Dual booting Ubuntu and windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, ubuntu, windows-xp, multi-boot

How much memory is required to dual boot the latest version of Ubuntu and windows (XP, although I'll upgrade to 7 soon)? The Ubuntu installation process says I'll need 6 GB, but is this just for the operating system, or does it include space for files? Also, am I right in presuming I won't need extra amounts of RAM, or a faster CPU, and how easy is it to remove dual booting?

Comment: 6GB is for the operating system.  Your files would require more.  Additional files you add woudl require more.

Answer (score 1):

Dual booting does not require the use of more ram. You are running one os at a time. If you were planning to run a virtual machine than more ram would be advised. Ubuntu, depending on if your system is optimized should use less system resources than Windows XP, how much ram do you have right now?

Comment: Two gigabytes..

Comment: 2gb is not enough I would recommend at least 4gb.

Comment: 2GB is fine even to run Windows 7.  It just won't be "lighting fast" but the hardware isn't new so thats to be expected.

Answer (score 0):

6 gb should be more than enough to hold anything you need in memory. Note that ram differs due to bus speed and quality.

My experience has been that ubuntu will out preform xp with the same specs.